# php dom + in xml delete the particular node

Tags: php, xml, dom

I want to delete particular node in XML based on the id I passed in the xml.
The below seems not working please help me.

```
$id  = $_GET['nodeId'];
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load('Seat_matrix.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$query = sprintf('/location/cubicle[./id = "%d"]', $id);
foreach($xpath->query($query) as $cubicle) {
    $record->parentNode->removeChild($cubicle);
}
$dom->save("Seat_matrix.xml");
```

## XML file

```
<location>

    <cubicle>
        <id> 6121</id>
        <status>2</status>
        <shift1>  
            <Employee1>Tom</Employee1>
        </shift1>           
        <shift2>  
            <Employee2>arum</Employee2>
        </shift2>
    </cubicle>
</location>
```

Comment: @Gordon, don't post answers as comments. Post that as an answer, because if that provides author with valid answer, author will not be able to accept a comment.

Comment: Hi I am getting Fatal error: Call to a member function removeChild() on a non-object on this line :$record->parentNode->removeChild($cubicle);

Answer (score 1):

You are using sprintf with %d but the element node contains " 6121" (mind the space in the beginning).

```
var_dump(sprintf('%d', ' 6121') === ' 6121'); // FALSE
```

Use %s instead. Also. there is no `$record` variable, so you have to change the code to

```
$cubicle->parentNode->removeChild($cubicle);
```